# How to solve this virtual memory question using C program?

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, virtual-memory

Simulate a virtual memory technique used in OS. Declare an array of huge size representing
the main memory and each array element represnts a frame. The array element is either zero
(if the frame is free) or Pr-Pg if the frame is being used by a process with
id . Given a process size, your program should determine the number of pages and assign 30% of frames to the process and remaining pages are assumed to be in virtual memory. Randomly select the pages from the process and assign a frame randomly, if the frame is free. This page-frame combination is maintained in a page table.
Given a process ID, generate a page reference string of length 10, simulate the execution of
the process, by checking page availability in physical memory and replacing the page if
necessary (by adopting a page replacement algorithm of your choice).

Write a menu driven program that (i) accepts the new process details and display the page
table for that process (ii) removes the process that was completed and upon completion
display the list of updated free frames, (iii) prints list of used / unused frames from the main
memory and (iv) Simulation results of the given process execution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not coded yet but my idea was to solve using demand paging.

Comment: Make an attempt and if you run into a specific problem or obstacles you can ask about it. See the meta FAQ about asking homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @ChandlerBing, try to code your idea and if you are stuck somewhere you can mention that here and people will help you. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Simulate **a** virtual memory technique...

What follows is a half-baken description of a complicated simulation instead of a concept.

I don't think this can be "solved", wherever it comes from.